# Trying to plot the Fourier transform solution to the heat equation on Mathematica

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, functions, fourier-analysis

I have gotten the solution of the heat equation as

[image]

where f(y) is the initial heat distribution which I have been given as f(x) = e^([Sigma]x^2).
I am supposed to plot this at the value of sigma 1, 2 and 3 and at different times.

So, on Wolfram Mathematica I have created the code [image]

When I run this code I just get error messages and I'm not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please also post the plain text version of code. can't copy code from image.

Answer (score 3):

See if this does what you want

[image]

### Code

```
ClearAll[f, x, a, t, y];
f[y_, a_] := Exp[a*y^2]
int = 1/Sqrt[4*Pi*a*t]*
  Integrate[ 
   Exp[-(x - y)^2/(4*a*t)]*f[y, a], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {t > 0, a > 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Abs@int[[1]] /. {t -> t0, a -> a0}, {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, .7}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red],
 {{t0, 1, "time"}, 1, 10, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {a0, {1, 2, 3}},
 TrackedSymbols :> {a0, t0}
 ]
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!